# Set width of text input form with blueprint

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I try to layout a form composed by a label and a text input. I want to set the width of the input element because the default is too wide.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span-24 last">
        <label for="age">Age: </label>
        <input class="text span-2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use `span-2` but the input text is displayed before the label.

Comment: Without seeing your css, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I am using blueprint CSS framework. The source is https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/blob/master/blueprint/screen.css

Answer (score 1):

```
input
{
    width: 300px;
}
```

will set the input width to 300px.